# Facebook "Like" button not incrementing Likes after implementing OG tags

Tags: facebook-like

I had a couple of likes go through on this site, but then I implemented the OG tags to correct the image that was being rendered. I'm not able to get the like button to increment the likes.

Would be grateful if someone could point out what is wrong here.

Site is [Greenside Films](http://www.greensidefilms.com.au/)

I have checked this page with FB lint and seems to not throw any exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liking the button refreshed the page.  So I looked at the DOM.  And the like button is hiding behind the div containing the Greenside films `hgroup id=logo`, so the click event is being processed by that div, causing a redirect to site again.  Reposition the like plugin to be not hiding behind other divs and that will fix your issue.

Comment: you're a star. must have changed the z-index at the same time as putting in the OG's. Thx mate.